# Webpack configuration for react-pdf in a Next.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

Im using `react-pdf` library in Next.js to generate PDF, view PDF and download that PDF in a Static Client Side Next.js Application (Server is not involved). But I can't set up the Webpack for Next.js as I don't have much knowledge about it.

This is what the required setup for Webpack is for `react-pdf`:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  /* ... */

  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      process: require.resolve('process/browser'),
      zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
      util: require.resolve('util'),
      buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
      asset: require.resolve('assert'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
  ],

  /* ... */
}
```

And this is the `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    // Important: return the modified config
    return config
  },
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `config` parameter that `next.config.js` gives us is like that objet we export in a normal `webpack.config.js`. Try with this setup of `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
      zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      util: require.resolve("util"),
      buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
      asset: require.resolve("assert"),
    };
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
        process: "process/browser",
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
};
```